# Problem with .setBounds(int, int, int, int) in ControlP5 library for Processing

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

I'm currently editing the library ControlP5 for Processing on Eclipse. The thing is that an unexpected error always comes out on the *ControlWindow.java* [file](https://github.com/sojamo/controlp5/blob/master/src/controlP5/ControlWindow.java#L846):

> The method .setBounds(int, int, int, int) is undefined for PApplet.

Here's the code of the method where the error occurs:

```
public ControlWindow setUndecorated( boolean theFlag ) {
    if ( theFlag != isUndecorated( ) ) {
        isUndecorated = theFlag;
        _myApplet.frame.removeNotify( );
        _myApplet.frame.setUndecorated( isUndecorated );
        _myApplet.setSize( _myApplet.width , _myApplet.height );
        _myApplet.setBounds( 0 , 0 , _myApplet.width , _myApplet.height );
        _myApplet.frame.setSize( _myApplet.width , _myApplet.height );
        _myApplet.frame.addNotify( );
    }
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Relevant line on Github: https://github.com/sojamo/controlp5/blob/master/src/controlP5/ControlWindow.java#L846

Comment: A few better ways of overcome the code amount limitation for questions would have been reducing the amount of code to just the relevant (method with error + relevant class variables definitions) or paste the full error message. Or both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the `PApplet` class doesn't contain this method, which is true if you are working with Processing 3.

`setBounds()` is a method found in Processing 2; the PApplet class used to inherit this method from `java.applet`, a class which it used to `extend`. In Processing 3, PApplet moved away from the Java applet class, but the controlp5 source code is old and was built with Processing 2, not 3.

---

> The `setBounds()` method specifies the size of the frame, and the location of the upper left corner.

... which is functionality covered by the `setSize()` and `setPosition()` methods, extant in Processing 3 (in fact the `setUndecorated()` method in which the error is found already calls `setSize()`).

So, remove the line to make the library compatible with Processing 3, or use Processing 2 instead.

Comment: To solve it, I just used _myApplet.frame.setBounds and it seemed to work